# KMM error: This API is internal in ktor and should not be used. It could be removed or changed without notice

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, xcode13

After updating Xcode to 13.0, I cannot run my iOS app which is using Kotlin Multiplatform. 
Build fails with `Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`, and it says that the error is:

> Task :shared:compileKotlinIos FAILED
> e: /Users...path.../KtorClient.kt: (134, 17): This API is internal in ktor and should not be used. It could be removed or changed without notice.

We have also had similar errors after updating to Xcode 13, but it is always something with shared KMM library, JDK etc... This error showed many times: 
`> Process ‘command ‘/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.12.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java’' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

134 line of `KtorClient.kt`:

```
override suspend fun createPassword(email: String, password: String): CreatePasswordResponse {
        return client.post {
            url {
                path("v1", "user", "create_password")
                body = LoginRequest(email, password)
            }
            headers {
/*134.line*/    append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, ContentType.Application.Json)
            }
        }
    }
```

We have tried deleting `XCWorkspace`, `Podfile.lock`, Pods folder, then pod reinstalling, deleting derived data, nothing helped.

We have also tried different versions of Ktor, JDK, nothing helped.

Also this command found on the Internet didnt help(they say you should run it after updating Xcode):

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-48127) of Ktor, related to [this fix](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-32443) in Kotlin.

Here's what [documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/request.html#headers) says:

> Note that the `StringValuesBuilder` class that exposes the append function is incorrectly marked with the `InternalAPI` annotation. This issue will be fixed in `v2.0.0`. As a workaround, you can add the `@OptIn(InternalAPI::class)` annotation to explicitly opt-in to use this API.

You can opt-in your specific line with `@OptIn(InternalAPI::class)`, or add this in your shared module `build.gradle.kts` to take effect on the whole module:

```
kotlin {
    // ..
    sourceSets {
        all {
            languageSettings.optIn("io.ktor.util.InternalAPI")
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This didnt help. My current version of Gradle is 1.6.0-RC.

Comment: @stackich try adding `@OptIn(InternalAPI::class)` before line 134